# Join [attribute*=value] selector with a :not(selector)

Tags: html, css

How can I use the `[attribute*=value]` selector with a `:not(selector)`?

I have a case in which I try to change some CSS rules to all pages except for Index.aspx but isn't working. My testings:

```
form:not([action*='Index']) .wk-path{
    margin: 18px 2%;
}
:not(form[action*='Index']) .wk-path{
    margin: 18px 2%;
}
```

Any idea? The rest of the pages do not contain the index literal in the url.

Comment: `form:not([action*='Index'])` is [perfectly valid](https://selectors.io/?s=form%3Anot(%5Baction*%3D%27Index%27%5D)). Do note that attribute selectors are case sensitive. If the attribute's value isn't exactly "Index" (like "index" or "INDEX") it won't be matched.

Comment: Are you trying to use both those rule-sets at the same time?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly The selector and the url were fine, but the action within the html contained a dot '.\Index'. I corrected that and it is already working.